# "Ruffled some conservative feathers in the audience"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[The da vinci code](https://books.google.jo/books?id=TB0ZDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=ruffle%20conservative%20feathers%20in%20the%20audience&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF8KK1gf3WAhUEAcAKHQYnDZwQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=ruffle%20conservative%20feathers%20in%20the%20audience&f=false)

> ... lecture – a slide show about pagan symbolism hidden in the stones of Chartres Cathedral – had probably **ruffled some conservative feathers in the audience**.

What is the meaning of the strong text, given above?

Answer (score 3):

***Ruffle feathers*** or ***ruffle some feathers*** means to cause irritation or annoyance. Think about grabbing a chicken and messing up its feathers. Here is the dictionary definition:

> *Informal* To upset or annoy people.
>
> Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruffle%20feathers

So, to ***ruffle some conservative feathers in the audience*** is a clever way of saying the following:

Some people in the audience who have conservative religious or social views were upset or annoyed [by the lecture].

Comment: Let's not go calling it "clever," shall we? It's really nothing more than a pedestrian cliché.

Comment: Ha, true. It's not Updike, that's for sure.